# explanation of matlab data types

Tags: matlab

I'm having trouble understanding the datatypes in matlab. Why does this produce two different datatypes?

```
data = [25 8 15 5 6 10 10 3 1 20 7]

v = [1:8]
```

The first one produces a 1x11 double somehow and the second one I believe produces a vector right? How is the first one able to work with findpeaks when the documentation says it wants a vector?

I was trying to do this.

http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/matlab/vector.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typing

```
data = [25 8 15 5 6 10 10 3 1 20 7]
v = [1:8]
whos
```

returns

```
data =
    25     8    15     5     6    10    10     3     1    20     7
v =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8

  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  data      1x11               88  double              
  v         1x8                64  double
```

so they are both the same, and I'd call them 1x11 vectors of doubles.

Comment: What does it mean on the right then? Why does it look like they are different types? http://www.pixhost.org/show/532/25812981_data.jpg

Comment: If a vector has 10 or fewer elements, the elements are listed, if there are more than 10 elements, just the size is displayed.

Comment: @coolstuff Don't forget to accept this answer if it fully solved your needs

Comment: @LuisMendo Done :). Sorry about that.